# Avoid propagating keydown events from dat.GUI to Three.js scene

Tags: javascript, events, three.js, dat.gui

I have this code (see bellow) with 2 event listeners:

```
renderer.domElement.addEventListener("pointerdown", changeColor, false);
document.addEventListener("keydown", changeColor, false);
```

They both trigger a color change in the cube. However, when I edit the input parameter in the GUI, `keydown` events also result in a color change, and I would like to avoid that.

I am guessing this is because I am using `document.addEventListener` for the `keydown` events. However, if I use `renderer.domElement.addEventListener` instead it wont work.

How can I avoid `keydown` events to propagate when editing GUI parameters?

### Code

```js
var renderer, controls, scene, camera;
var cube;

init();

function init() {

    // Scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xb0b0b0);

    // Camera
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(30, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.set(300, 300, 300);
    camera.up.set(0, 0, 1);

    // Light
    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xcccccc, 0.2);
    scene.add(ambientLight);

    // Helpers
    var helpers = new THREE.Group();
    var grid = new THREE.GridHelper(200, 10);
    grid.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
    var axis = THREE.AxisHelper(100);
    helpers.add(grid);
    helpers.add(axis);
    scene.add(helpers);

    // Renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // Controls
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

    // Event listeners
    controls.addEventListener("change", render, false);

    // Draw the cube
    var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 50, 50, 50 );
        var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x000088 } );
        cube = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial );
    scene.add(cube);
    
    // GUI
    params = {
        size: 50,
    };
    var gui = new dat.GUI();
    gui.add(params, "size", 0.0, 100, 1);
    
    // Listeners
    renderer.domElement.addEventListener("pointerdown", changeColor, false);
    document.addEventListener("keydown", changeColor, false);

    // Render
    render();
}

function changeColor(event) {
    cube.material.color.set(Math.random() * 0xffffff);
    cube.material.needsUpdate = true;
    render();
}

function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.126.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.126.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/js/DAT.GUI.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this is the best approach, but you can ignore keydown events from the event handler by inspecting its target. If the target is an `input`, then do nothing:

```js
function changeColor(event) {
    // Ignore key event when editing dat.GUI input values
    if (event.target.localName == "input") {
        return;
    }
    // [...]
}
```